# Can't access Docker images when using user namespace

Tags: ubuntu, docker, namespaces, privileges, docker-image

On my Ubuntu 14.04 server I have Docker image named `virtual_machine`. When I do not use user namespace (`--userns-remap=myuser`) I can see docker images using `docker images` command. When I enable namespaces on docker daemon, images can't be seen. User that starts docker and creates container, also named in `--userns-remap=myuser` is user who doesn't have almost any privileges on host.

I tried giving him full ownership and all privileges on `/var/lib/docker/` directory, but result is the same.
What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

When the docker daemon is started with the user namespace activated, it doesn't look for images in `/var/lib/docker` but in a subdirectory like`/var/lib/docker/xxxx:yyyy`, xxxx and yyyy depending on your /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid.

Then images need to be built again.

Old images are not lost though, and are usable if the user namespace option is deactivated.